# How to query on OneToOne relation of a related_name object in django

Tags: django, django-orm, one-to-one

I have this model:

```
class ProgramRequirement(Model):
    program = OneToOneField(Program, related_name='program_requirement')
    prereq_program = ForeignKey(Program, related_name='prereq_program_requirement')
    is_english_required = BooleanField()
```

and this model

```
class Program(Model):
    field_1 = ...
    field_3 = ...
```

I need to write a query that would return **the primary key of the programs of which is_english_required of the prereq_program is True**.

I tried this but it seems to be a wrong query:

```
ProgramRequirement.objects.filter(prereq_program__prereq_program_requirement__is_english_required =True).values_list('program__pk', flat=True)
```

However, it is not returning the correct result.

I am not sure if it is what I want but I am also thinking of this:

```
Program.objects.filter(prereq_program_requirement__is_english_required =True).values_lis('pk', flat=True)
```

Any idea of how to retrieve do the abovementioned result?

Comment: Your last query seems fine (to me).

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```py
ProgramRequirement.objects.filter(prereq_program__programrequirement__is_english_required = True).values('pk')
```